# PHP replacement is empty, or not replaced

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Well im trying to replace the first number in a string in PHP, but not behaves as spected.

```
$str = 'A12:B17';
$newvalue = '987';
echo preg_replace('/(^[A-Za-z])\d+(.*)/', '\1'.$newvalue.'\2', $str);
```

The problem is \1 is well replaced when i put it alone, but when i put $newvalue and \2 the first \1 is ignored

input1:

```
echo preg_replace('/(^[A-Za-z])\d+(.*)/', '\1'.$newvalue.'\2', $str);
```

output1:

```
87:B17 // dissapears first character :/
```

input2:

```
echo preg_replace('/(^[A-Za-z])\d+(.*)/', '\1'.$newvalue.'\2', $str);
```

output2:

`A`

desired result: 
`A987:B17`

- NOTE: I need a regex solution, this applies to other similar problems.

Comment: "I need a regexp". I love to see that kind of things... What do you know if regexps are the best tool for the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo preg_replace('/(^[A-Za-z])\d+(.*)/', '${1}' . $newvalue . '${2}', $str);
//=> OUTPUT: A987:B17
```

Problem is that in your code back reference variable `\1` is becoming `\1987` and that's why showing empty value. `${1}` keeps it separate from `987` and hence values are properly replaced.

Comment: It'd be nice if you actually explained your solution

Comment: Yes I was adding it while you wrote.

Comment: Nice this solve my problem, i didn't realize the \1987, i spend lot of time on this, TY !

Answer (score 1):

[*anubhava*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21491918/1715579) is great, but you could also use a lookbehind [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^[A-Za-z])\d+/', $newvalue, $str);
```

The lookbehind ensures that the matched string (`\d+`) immediately follows a string which matches the pattern, `^[A-Za-z]`. However, unlike your original, the portion of the string which matches the lookbehind is not captured in the match, so the entire match is `12`.

And just to provide yet another solution, you could also use a callback:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(^[A-Za-z])\d+/', function($m) use (&$newvalue) { 
    return $m[1].$newvalue;
}, $str);
```

Comment: @anubhava answer solve my problem, but im curius about the first part of your expression, can you explain it?, thank you.